# UML Class Diagram for Online Takeaway Ordering Service (Similar to JustEat)

Tags: oop, uml, class-diagram

I am currently in the process of setting up Class Diagrams for an Online Takeaway Service, similar to that of JustEat.

I don't really have much experience when it comes to creating UML Diagrams but I was wondering if someone could take a look at my current Class Diagram and perhaps give me some advice or correction to point me in the right direction?

I have attached a [SCREENSHOT](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rHdv1.jpg) of my current progress.

Many Thanks, Jay

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing the business case it's impossible to elaborate on semantics. However, here a few (mostly syntactical) tips:

- Leave away the `cls` prefix in your classes. A capital first letter already indicates that its a class (or a type in general)
- In the same way let all your attributes and operations start wit a lower case letter. It follows the same common convention as the previous.
- Use role names. E.g. between `Customer` and `Cart` place the role name `cart` near the `Cart` to indicate that `Customer` has a `cart` attribute which is of type `Cart`.
- I would probably decouple the authentication from the `Customer` class and create an `Authentication` class on its own.

I assume that the missing parameters and general `void` return values are due to the early stage of your design.